# Smart way for escaping List of special Characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of special characters:
`+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ~ * ? \ :`

I want to escape all of them with a leading `\\` except of `\` that needs only ohne leading backslash `\`
e.g. a string that is `(1+1)\2` must be changed to `\\(1\\+1\\)\\2`
In fact it prepends two backslashes to each defined special character, and only one backslash to a backslash.

I wrote this function, that works actually quite good:

```js
function escapeSpecialCharacters(input) {
  var output = input.replace(/\+/g, "\\\+")
    .replace(/\-/g, "\\\-")
    .replace(/\&/g, "\\\&")
    .replace(/\|/g, "\\\|")
    .replace(/\!/g, "\\\!")
    .replace(/\(/g, "\\\(")
    .replace(/\)/g, "\\\)")
    .replace(/\{/g, "\\\{")
    .replace(/\}/g, "\\\}")
    .replace(/\[/g, "\\\[")
    .replace(/\]/g, "\\\]")
    .replace(/\^/g, "\\\^")
    .replace(/\~/g, "\\\~")
    .replace(/\*/g, "\\\*")
    .replace(/\?/g, "\\\?")
    .replace(/\:/g, "\\\:")
    .replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

  return output;
}
console.log(escapeSpecialCharacters("(1+1)\\2"));
```

But im not happy with the current implementation. 
Because i think its quite hard to read an to maintain.

Is there any other "smarter" solution/framework available for this problem? I was thinking of a function that uses a given list of special characters to replace them in my string.

Comment: @hindmost I doubt it is a dupe

Comment: Your function doesn't do what you claim it does. It only prepends one backslash in front of each special character.

Comment: This is not exactly regex escape but the solution show how to do this in single replace, just add rest of special characters to regex in accepted answer.

Comment: @Rajesh: i fixed the your last line. Now the console log is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did see this regex:

```
/([-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])/g
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/2813224)? Using `String.raw` on a template literal of input so octal can be interpreted as a literal `\2`. `\` being exception (for some unfathomable reason) you can chain `.replace()`.

```js
const escape = string => string.replace(/([-\/^$*+?.()|[\]{}])/g, `\\$1`).replace(/([\\])/g, `\\\$1`);

console.log(escape(String.raw`(1+1)\2`));
```

Comment: your snippet delivers \\\2 for \2, but i expect \\2 in this case

Comment: looks great! Still hard to read, but less error-prone than my implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @DieGraueEminenz Indeed, arrow functions are hard for me to read as well, but I persist in using them so they'll eventually become second nature. You're very welcome, don't forget to check the checkmark ✅ if this answer resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution. I've just loop through all the characters one by one and checking which one is matching and then just append forward slashes as prefix.

```js
const specialChars  = ["+", "-" ,"&", "|", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "~", "*", "?", "\\", ":",];
let string = `(1+1)\\2`; // double slash is needed to avaoid escaping

let changedString = string.split('').reduce((newString, char) => {
  if(specialChars.includes(char) && char !== '\\') {
    return newString += `\\\\${char}`;
  } else if(char == "\\") {
      return newString += `\\${char}`;
  } else {
      return newString += char;
  }
}, '')

console.log(changedString)
```